# getting a execution of python after installation , attached file for same

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image]

Please help with error (plase refer attachment). I tried to install python 3.6 for windows 7(64 bit). when I tried to run python I got an  error. 
What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling then re-installing? Do you have a 64-bit system?

Comment: yes almost 3 times

Comment: Please describe the steps you went through when you attempted to install the software, and what you mean by "opened this python."

Comment: downloaded  python 3.6 for windows  7--> opened executable file -->installed python......but when i tried to run i got thr following error(please refer attached file)

Comment: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll-is-missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your Windows version, you may need to obtain [Update for Universal C Runtime in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows).

First, uninstall Python. Do the above update. Restart your machine. Then, re-install Python.

Note, there are separate update versions for 32-bit and  64-bit Windows versions.

Hope that helps.

Comment: how ? I'm new to  stackoverflow?

Comment: Please take a look at [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).